# Select Max(Field) not working

Tags: sql, db2, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following issue:

```
SELECT MAX(SEQUENCE) FROM TABLE1
WHERE FIELD99= 'NUMBER'
```

That query is bringing the MAX value of Field1, and it's working perfectly.
Now I want to join this information with another table to gather additional data, and I'm using this:

```
SELECT MAX(B.SEQUENCE), A.COUNTRY, A.COMPANY, 
A.DOCNUMBER, B.USERID, B.REASON
FROM TABLE1 A
INNER JOIN TABLE2 B
ON A.DOCNUMBER=B.DOCNUMBER
WHERE A.DOCNUMBER='NUMBER'
GROUP BY B.SEQUENCE, A.COUNTRY, A.COMPANY, A.DOCNUMBER, B.USERID, B.REASON
```

I know the issue is the Grouping, but I can't figure out, I have tried several ways, I've noticed that when I removed all other fields it's bringing only the data I want.

If I run the first example given, I will get result:
007, which is the Max Value of Field SEQUENCE.
If I run the other Query, I will get:

```
001 + all the other fields
002 + all the other fields
003 + all the other fields
004 + all the other fields
005 + all the other fields
006 + all the other fields
007 + all the other fields
```

I want the result to bring the same row as the first Query with the added data in Select

I was able to do this Query and solve the issue

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.REFFSEQU, A.CTRYCODE, A.COMPCODE, A.INVONUMB, A.REFFERRS, A.REFFERBY              
FROM TABLE1 A, TABLE2 B                                    
WHERE A.CTRYCODE=B.CTRYCODE AND A.COMPCODE=B.COMPCODE AND A.INVONUMB=B.INVONUMB
AND B.INVOCRDT > '20180101'                                                    
AND (A.REFFSEQU = ANY                                                          
 (SELECT MAX(REFFSEQU)                                                         
 FROM TABLE1 AS D                                                    
 WHERE D.CTRYCODE=A.CTRYCODE AND D.COMPCODE=A.COMPCODE                         
 AND D.INVONUMB= A.INVONUMB))                                                  
AND A.REFFERRS = 'DUPLICATION, RECORD REJEC'
```

This is the result, sorry not familiar on how to do a Table here

```
REFFSEQU    CTRYCODE    COMPCODE    INVONUMB    REFFERRS                       REFFERBY
001           631          01   number1         DUPLICATION, RECORD REJEC             id  
002           631          01   number2         DUPLICATION, RECORD REJEC             id
002           631          01   number3         DUPLICATION, RECORD REJEC             id
007           631          01   number4         DUPLICATION, RECORD REJEC             id
007           631          01   number5         DUPLICATION, RECORD REJEC             id
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: From which table FIELD22, FIELD33, FIELD56 fields come from ? From table1 or table2 ?

Comment: I've edited the post with the information requested

Comment: The second select is grouping by the the field you are trying to find the `max()` of. This is unnecessary as each group will contain a single sequence number, and the max of that sequence number is that sequence number itself. In this case you may as well just remove the `max()`.

Comment: is sequence in `table1` or `table2`? Is sequence in table1 and table2 the same? Or should a proper join of `table1` and `table2` include both `docnumber` and `sequence`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a CTE to do this. It will simplify the grouping.

```
with tmp as (
  select docnumber, 
         max(sequence) as sequence,
         country,
         company
    from table1
    group by docnumber)
select a.sequence, a.country, a.company, a.docnumber, b.userid, b.reason
  from tmp a
    join table2 b on a.docnumber = b.docnumber
    where a.docnumber = 'NUMBER'
```

Note, I am using sequence from `table1` rather than `table2`.

**Edit:** This is an initial guess based on the comments:

```
with tmp as (
  select docnumber, max(sequence) as sequence
    from table1
    group by docnumber),
tmp2 as (
  select distinct docnumber
    from table2
    where reason = 'Duplicated')
select a.sequence, a.country, a.company, a.docnumber, b.userid, b.reason
  from tmp a
    join table2 b on a.docnumber = b.docnumber
    join tmp2 c on a.docnumber = c.docnumber
    where a.docnumber = 'NUMBER'
```

You would not need the distinct in the `tmp2` definition if no more than one sequence for each docnumber has a reason of 'Duplicated'.

Comment: This is working so far. The issue is that I need 2 additional Fields from Table1 and when I do that, the grouping is inconsistent. I need to use DOCNUMBER, MAX(SEQUENCE), USERID, REASON but when I add those 2 field, the grouping stops working. And if I add those 2 fields to the GROUP BY I go back to having all results instead of MAX. The issue is REASON, because it does not have the same value in every row

Comment: So what `reason` and `userid` do you want for a given doc number?

Comment: The idea is to search for documents created from (Field> XX/XX2018) XX/XX/2018, and select the MAX(SEQUENCE) when the REASON is "Duplicated"

Comment: @UrielNicolas Can you give us some data examples?

Comment: @UrielNicolas I just saw that you edited in more descriptive field names (you did miss one I think in the first query), so I adjusted my answer to match those fields except I am using sequence from table1.

Comment: @UrielNicolas in the question it appears that reason and userid are in table2, but in your comments here you say they are in table2. Which is it? Having sample data will make this a lot easier. Please edit your question to make sure it is accurate, and delete out inaccurate comments here.